# cross compilation application qt from Windows to ubuntu

Tags: qt, cross-compiling

I have developped an application on Windows (which works well). I have to now execute this application on Ubuntu. How can I deploy my application ? Is it possible to cross compiled (and if yes how). I haven't seen any tutorial (only Linux to Windows).

Thak you for your help

Comment: The easiest way is to have Linux on a virtual machine and to build your application there

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cross-compile to "Linux", because that's not an OS.

Certain system-level libraries and interfaces differ from distribution to distribution, making it nearly impossible to get a one-binary-covers-all.

Setting up a cross-compiler is generally a pain in the... nuts, and for Linux->Windows, there is no free alternative (a Windows license isn't free). For Windows->Linux, you can install the distribution you are targetting and compile it natively (perhaps in a virtual machine). This guarantees compatibility with the OS you're targetting and is much more reliable than cross-compiling.